# Найти наиболее отдаленное от среднего значения

Tags: mysql

Найти такое значение, которое является наиболее отдаленным от среднего арифметического в поле таблицы.
 Например:
имеем поле price со значениями 200 500 700 1000 1200 - Среднее 720.

От 720 до 1200 = 480
От 720 до 200 = 520
Значит 200 и будет самым отдаленным, Но как мне написать запрос на вывод этого наиболее отдаленного?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине самое отдаленное от среднего значения = 950.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable(number INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Получается такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    testtable
WHERE
    number = (SELECT MAX(ABS(number - (SELECT AVG(number) FROM testtable))) + (SELECT avg(number) FROM testtable) FROM testtable);
```

Работает только с положительными числами